# Default date in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, date

i am facing issue while creating table where in that one column which is set to default value of current date........i would stress this point "that i need only date not time along with that"....i would be really thankfull to those who tries to help me....

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650724/mysql-syntax-for-setting-default-date/1650799

Comment: No it's not, (s)he wants a dynamic date defaulting to today

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to get MySQL to insert the current date for you when a row is created automatically, you can set it to NOW() in the INSERT query.  Or, in the code for your software, you can set the date to the current date in the INSERT query.

MySQL does not support a default of the current date for DATE or DATETIME.

Comment: +1 The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out this set yuor field to a 'Date' not 'DateTime'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

> The DATE type is used when you need
>   only a date value, without a time
>   part. MySQL retrieves and displays
>   DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.
>   The supported range is '1000-01-01' to
>   '9999-12-31'.